# tooltip for select in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of car that can be selected from dropdown as

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

this code gives me code of dropdown, I need a hover message as "select your car" on hovering on the box. There is a option of select that gives  message for each option, however my need is to display tooltip only when hovering the select box.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add a title attribute:

```
<select title="Select your car">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't look that great though.  If you want a fancier tooltip you'd have to go the JavaScript route.